# if-if-else vs if-elif-else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Why is the 'else' statement getting printed even if a correct choice is picked?

```
    ch=0
    print"Do you need Ice-Cream?"
    ans=raw_input()
    if ans=='y':
        print"Pick a flavor"
        ch=raw_input() # ch is a string
        if ch=='1':
            print"Vanilla"
        if ch=='2':
            print"Chocolate"
        if ch=='3':
            print"Strawberry"
        if ch=='4':
            print"Kiwi"
        if ch=='5':
            print"orange"
        if ch=='6':
            print"mango"
        if ch=='7':
            print"pineapple"
        if ch=='8':
            print"grapes"               
        print"You are done picking up a flavor, pay now"    
    if ans=='n':
        print"Good, you can go!"
    else:
        print"wrong choice"
```

Output is printing "wrong choice" even if a valid choice is selected.

Comment: In Python, "else" is optional, so why it must get printed ?

Comment: Did you mean `elif ans=='n':`?

Comment: You don't need to initialize `ans=""` before you call `ans=raw_input()` any more than you would need to assign  value to `ans` before `ans=""`. The same goes for `ch=0`, where assigning an integer value to a variable that will be assigned a string value makes even less sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two conditions not one.

1. The first condition checks `ans` against `'y'`.

   If `ans` is `'y'` the user gets to input an integer 1-8 and the appropriate string will be printed to the console. Processing then moves to the second condition (#2).

   If `ans` is not `'y'` then the user dose not give any input and processing moves to the second condition (#2).
2. The second condition checks `ans` against `'n'`.

   If `ans` is `'n'` then "Good, you can go!" is printed to the console and processing continues skipping the `else` block.

   If `ans` is not `'n'` (which would be the case that user entered `'y'`) then the `else` block is executed printing "wrong choice" to the console.

What is happening is you have your logic setup that any input other than `'n'` will print "wrong choice" eventually. You want a single decision from the users initial input. Currently your logic makes two.

Use the `if elif else` construct.

Comment: I need help in getting my account unlocked. I am a beginner and really need help in programming. I am also new to stackoverflow.com.Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Because the if-statement checking "y" and the second if-statement checking "n" are two different.  The else is only connected to the second if-statement with the "n"-check.  You want to have the outermost statements like

```
if "y":
    ....
elif "n":
    ....
else:
    ....
```

Comment: So you mean, I should change all 'if' except first to 'elif' so that else gets isolated?

Comment: The difference between 1) `if-if-else` and 2) `if-elif-else` is that in case 1) the else is only reacting on the second if-statement.  The first if is completely alone and no matter what happens in the first if, it will always check the second if, and eventually go into the else (if the second is not true).  With 2) the entire code-block is connected as one "code-flow", it will first check the if, then the elif and lastly the else, depending on the outcome in the if and elif.  In your case you want it as I wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're conflating your series of `if`s with a series of `if`-`elifs`.

Note that this:

```
if cond0:
    ...
if cond1:
    ...
else:
    bar()
```

is *not* the same as:

```
if cond0:
    ...
elif cond1:
    ...
else:
    bar()
```

If `cond0` is `True`, then the former will call `bar()`, while the latter will not. In the former, it is just an `if` followed by a *completely separate* `if-else`.

It might help to write the former like this:

```
if cond0:
    ...

# Note spacing here, emphasizing that the above construct is separate from the one below.

if cond1:
    ...
else:
    bar()
```

Comment: whats the difference between 1st and 3rd way of if-else?

Comment: From the point of view of the interpreter - nothing at all. To a human, it might emphasize that these are two separate, sequential, constructs. First the first `if` will be evaluated. No matter what the outcome, the second `if`-`else- will be evaluated. The spaces in between are just meant to emphasize that to a human.

Answer (score 1):

`ans` isn't `'n'` so the `else` clause fires.  You probably want an `elif`:

```
if ans == 'y':
    ...
elif ans == 'n':
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else` in this chunk of code is only referring to the `if ans=='n'`.

It's not taking into account your first if statement. You're going to want to change it to this

```
elif ans=='n':
    print"Good, you can go!"
else:
    print"wrong choice"
```